# ec2 instance doesn't start

Tags: amazon-ec2, startup

I have an EBS backed EC2 instance, which doesn't start The system log says:

```
    [    0.881605] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 1196k

    Loading, please wait...

        %GCouldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
    Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
    Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
    Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
    Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
    Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
    Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
    Begin: Loading essential drivers... ...
    [    1.006136] fuse init (API version 7.12)

    Done.
    Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ...
    Done.
    Begin: Mounting root file system... ...
    Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ...
    Done.
    Begin: Waiting for root file system... ...
    Done.
    Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ...
    Done.
    [    1.320965] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds

    [    1.320984] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with writeback data mode.

    Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ...
    Done.
    Done.
    Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ...
    Begin: Starting AppArmor profiles ...
    chroot: cannot execute /etc/apparmor/initramfs: No such file or directory
    Failure: AppArmor profiles failed to load
    Done.
    [    3.741464] EXT3-fs warning: checktime reached, running e2fsck is recommended

    [    3.742696] EXT3 FS on sda1, internal journal

    init: console-setup main process (2139) terminated with status 1


        %Ginit: plymouth main process (341) killed by SEGV signal

    init: plymouth-splash main process (2431) terminated with status 2

    init: squid main process (2493) killed by ABRT signal

    cloud-init running: Sun, 02 Dec 2012 20:36:06 +0000. up 5.77 seconds
    init: ureadahead-other main process (2511) terminated with status 4

    swapon: /dev/sda3: swapon failed: Device or resource busy
    mountall: swapon /dev/sda3 [2513] terminated with status 255
    mountall: Problem activating swap: /dev/sda3
    init: ureadahead-other main process (2522) terminated with status 4

    mountall: Disconnected from Plymouth
    Close
```

Does this mean there is a problem with my sda1 disk? I have a snapshot that I could use instead.

Comment: You can snapshot your volume, mount it to another instance, and check what's going on.  It's likely the volume is toast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definitely a problem with the instance as the system isn't able to mount swap or your apparmor profiles.

Is this a new instance from the community AMIs or a custom built one?

Using your snapshot would be advisable until you can determine what caused this instance to not be able to mount swap.